# How can I make the react-bootstrap Navbar stay fixed="top" and have sidebar under it

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I learn ReactJs and the react-bootstrap `NavBar`. I wanted to have a `fixed="top"` `NavBar` so it is always visible. So the content is scrolled under it!

The two problems i have here in my [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/greta100-reactbootsrap-navbar-1-l9c1s?file=/src/components/elements/NavBar.jsx) is that the side-bare that the `NavBar` menu opens is under the `NavBar`.
I think I know why it's because of the `fixed="top"` property on the `NavBar`. I have tried to understand how it works and it looks like I have to calculate the `NavBar` height and set that as top margin for the side-bare. Any better idea or if I'm wrong here please advice?

My other problem is the size of the 3-strip icon Hamburger menu. How can I change it to be bigger? I read the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) and I see no information for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `.side-drawer`, you can adjust the `top` property (e.g., `top: 146px`) or you can add some padding to the sidebar element so that it makes space for the header.

```
.side-drawer {
  padding-top: 160px;
}
```

As for the hamburger button dimensions, I recommend resizing `.navbar-toggler-icon`

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler-icon {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

[image: Edit Greta100 React.Bootsrap Navbar 1 (forked)]

Comment: Would be nice to get the NavBar height and use it for the side bar top margin. was thinking maybe use Redux mapStateToProp for that what you think? Or is that overdoing it?

Comment: if the navbar height is static it would generally be better if you do it all in your stylesheet. if the height is dynamic, then you can opt to consider using custom scripts to calculate the concerned elements' dimensions